# Code connect to Google Analytics API with C# error

Tags: c#, api, google-analytics

I trying using Google Analytics with C# to get stats information to display in my webiste
Here is my code

```
      public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string userName = "admin@email.com";
        string passWord = "mypass";
        string profileId = "ga:xxxxxxxx";
        string key = "2d751338cb092ef8da65f716e37a48604386c9sw";
       string dataFeedUrl = "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data"+key;

        var service = new AnalyticsService("API Project");

        service.setUserCredentials(userName, passWord);

        var dataQuery = new DataQuery(dataFeedUrl)
        {
            Ids = profileId,
            Metrics = "ga:pageviews",
            Sort = "ga:pageviews",
            GAStartDate = new DateTime(2010, 3, 1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
            GAEndDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        };

        var dataFeed = service.Query(dataQuery);

        var totalEntry = dataFeed.Entries[0];

        ViewData["Total"] = ((DataEntry)(totalEntry)).Metrics[0].Value;

        dataQuery.GAStartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        dataQuery.GAEndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        dataFeed = service.Query(dataQuery);

        var yesterdayEntry = dataFeed.Entries[0];
        ViewData["Yesterday"] = ((DataEntry)(yesterdayEntry)).Metrics[0].Value;
        dataQuery.GAStartDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        dataQuery.GAEndDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        dataFeed = service.Query(dataQuery);

        var todayEntry = dataFeed.Entries[0];
        ViewData["Today"] = ((DataEntry)(todayEntry)).Metrics[0].Value;
        return View(dataFeed.Entries);
    }
```

But when i run the code it always said "{"Invalid credentials"}"
Not sure why i facing this error while i checked many time about the key,username,password and profileId
Anyone facing this problem,can help me?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that your url is wrong. try in this way (you are missing `?key=`).

```
string dataFeedUrl = "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?key="+key;
```

refer this google [example](https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/Analytics_DataFeed_Sample/dataFeed.cs) where there is this example that should help you

```
 public DataFeedExample()
    {

      // Configure GA API.
      AnalyticsService asv = new AnalyticsService("gaExportAPI_acctSample_v2.0");

      // Client Login Authorization.
      asv.setUserCredentials(CLIENT_USERNAME, CLIENT_PASS);

      // GA Data Feed query uri.
      String baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data";

      DataQuery query = new DataQuery(baseUrl);
      query.Ids = TABLE_ID;
      query.Dimensions = "ga:source,ga:medium";
      query.Metrics = "ga:visits,ga:bounces";
      query.Segment = "gaid::-11";
      query.Filters = "ga:medium==referral";
      query.Sort = "-ga:visits";
      query.NumberToRetrieve = 5;
      query.GAStartDate = "2010-03-01";
      query.GAEndDate = "2010-03-15";
      Uri url = query.Uri;
      Console.WriteLine("URL: " + url.ToString());


      // Send our request to the Analytics API and wait for the results to
      // come back.

      feed = asv.Query(query);


    }
```

refer also this [guide](http://www.daimto.com/google-analytics-api-v3-with-c/) to configure your project

Also follow this guide to use  [OAuth 2.0](http://forums.asp.net/t/1988386.aspx?Google%20analytics%20OAuth%202%200)

Comment: Yes,i tried to change
 string dataFeedUrl = "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?key=" + key;
.But still not working,the same error i mentioned above

Comment: there is a wrong `;` try in this way `"https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?key="+key;`

Comment: Same error with string dataFeedUrl = "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?key="+key;

Comment: which version of API are you using?

Comment: I am using version v3

Comment: string dataFeedUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly";
I tried this and have  same error :(

Comment: I think my code is very similar which the code you gave me!
The line code i getting error is:
 var dataFeed = service.Query(dataQuery);

Comment: did you folow the guide that I have attached to the answer?

Comment: Is the user that you are using administrator? If yes I think that it should be a problem

Comment: yes,user i am using is administrator,even i go to https://console.developers.google.com/ to create the key,turn on the APIs i am using and no luck!!

Comment: new update.. follow that guide and I tink that you will get successfull with OAuth 2.0